# Issue with popViewController and pushController

Tags: iphone, ios5, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

I'm facing issue with redirecting the viewControllers using pop/pushViewControllers. I've three view controller like below image -

[image: Control Flow]

In my 3rd view i've some `ToggleButton` based on that `toggleButton` the data which is in 2nd View will change. After, changing something on 3rd view and press `Done` button in my 3rd View i just started my 2nd ViewController using `pushViewController` And, the changes are occured successfully.

But, what was the issue is, when i try to press the back button on my 2nd view page its redirecting me again to 3rd viewController (Because of pushViewController)

I try to start my 2nd view using `popViewController` but, its giving exception.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.
```

I've used below code -

```
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
second.array = resultArray;
second.indexValue = ind;
[self.navigationController popToViewController:second animated:YES];
```

How do i solve this issue? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 3rd viewcontroller you just need to call this method to pop to 2nd viewcontroller :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

EDIT :

For notifying the second vc for data change you can use delegate. Follow this :

On ThirdViewController.h

```
@protocol DataChangeProtocol;
@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic,assign) id<DataChangeProtocol> delegate;

@end


@protocol DataChangeProtocol

- (void)thirdViewcontroller:(ThirdViewController*)vc dataChangedto:(NSDictionary *)changedData;

@end
```

And before pushing the thridVC from secondVC assign secondVC as the delegate of thirdVC :

```
ThirdViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc]init..];
thirdVC.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdVC animated:YES];
```

and in SecondViewController.m

```
- (void)thirdViewcontroller:(ThirdViewController*)vc dataChangedto:(NSDictionary *)changedData {
 // Change your values in the UI using the passed value from changedData.

}
```

Comment: Its fine. Then, how will i represent the changes whatever i've done in my 3rd View to 2nd viewController?

Comment: use delegate to pass the changes to second viewcontroller to thridviewcontroller. or even better keep the changes in a central datamodel where the second viewcontroller can access it when it appears.

Comment: How can i do this? Is there any example for this functionality?

Comment: have added a few code as edit in the answer. hope this will help

Comment: Will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to your current previous view controller then you have to do this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Its fine. Then, how will i represent the changes whatever i've done in my 3rd View to 2nd viewController?

Answer (score 1):

You create our viewcontroller:

```
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

and then you want to pop it from your stack but this controller is not in the stack, bacause you create it in the third viewController.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //it used in first class
     SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
second.array = resultArray;
second.indexValue = ind;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
    //it move to second class

    //it used in second class
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //it move to firsr class
```